# Pass value between multiple routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
route.post('/register',function(req,res){
   //done registration
   // assume I have my token value here as 'abc'
})

route.post('/verify',function(req,res){
 // how do I get 'abc' here?
})
```

I'm doing a API for user register/login system, I'm stuck in get verification code from other route.

Comment: Use a session so you can set a value for this browser in the session or set a cookie with a specific value in it.  FYI, a session will use a cookie to keep track of the requesting browser so it can tie the browser making the request to the right session.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to pass data between two requests is by using sessions.  You can do this pretty easily with Express using middleware.  Two libraries to check out are https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session and https://github.com/expressjs/session.

An example of doing what you want with express-session is:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'super secure string that only the server knows',
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));

app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    // access the session via req.session
    req.session.token = "abc";
    // ... response code ...
});

app.post('/verify', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.token);
    // ... response code ...
});
```